# How do I automatically get paredit in a emacs nrepl session?

Tags: emacs, clojurescript

I have the following line in my emacs init file.

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons `("\*nrepl\*" . paredit-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

I check that this works by creating a new buffer called *nrepl* `Ctrl-x-f *nrepl*`. Yes, the *nrepl* buffer has Paredit active, paredit-mode was enabled.

I close the *nrepl* buffer without saving it.

I start up a nrepl session by typing `M-x nrepl-jack-in`. The nrepl server starts up and I am presented with the nrepl repl. The nrepl repl is also called *nrepl*, however Paredit is **not** enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing buffers and files: `auto-mode-alist` matches file names against regexps to decide which mode to use when editing those files.  But *nrepl* is a buffer that does not contain a file, so `auto-mode-alist` has no effect for it.
Instead, you probably want to figure out which major-mode *nrepl* uses and then use `(add-hook '<the-major-mode>-hook 'paredit-mode)`.

Comment: <the-major-mode> of "nrepl-connected" seems to do the trick. For a grand total of:
    (add-hook 'nrepl-connected-hook 'paredit-mode)

Answer (score 5):

To put it simply - you need the following code:

```
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode) ; for nrepl.el <= 0.1.8
(add-hook 'nrepl-repl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode) ; for nrepl.el > 0.1.8
```

Which is equivalent to the longer form:

```
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook (lambda () (paredit-mode +1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
```

is what they suggest on the [nrepl github page](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el)